# C - No output in the program

Tags: c, gcc

I made a stack and i am using the isEmpty function but the output is not coming. I trued manually using the `gcc` command and also using the code runner extension.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Stack
{
    int top;
    int size;
    int *arr;
} Stack;

int isEmpty(Stack *st)
{
    if (st->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Stack *st;
    st->top = -1;
    st->size = 10;
    st->arr = (int *)malloc(st->size * sizeof(int));
    int i = isEmpty(st);
    if (i == 1)
    {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The stack is not empty\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The file is named Stack.c.
There is one more thing that the basic hello world program is working perfectly

Comment: If you want `st` to be a pointer, you need to `st = malloc(sizeof(Stack))`. If you don't need `st` to be a pointer, then the simplest thing to do is `Stack st = {-1,10,NULL};` and then `st.arr = malloc(st.size * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Stack *st;
st->top = -1;
```

You invoked undefined behavior by accessing uninitialized pointer `st->top = -1;`.

You should initialize `st` first:

```
Stack *st = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
```

Comment: thank you. i did not know about that function

Comment: thank you. I was stumped as i am fairly new to c language as i am a python programmer by large

Comment: @VedantMatanhelia You're welcome :-) You may find [this](http://c-faq.com/) useful moving forward.